# How can I set Button at bottom div by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my HTML I use divine into 2 `col-md-6` and in left side I've a picture and right side I've a text , not sure maybe I should use jQuery `.height()`?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 50px">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6" style="float: right" style=""> 
    <div style="background-color:red;height:456px;width:100%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6" style="text-align: right;">       
    <h1 id="head-font" style="font-weight: bolder; margin: 0;">TITLE</h1> 
    <label id="p-font" class="text-font">INFO</label>
    <p class="title text-font" id="p-font" >promotion description</p>
      
    // this buttuon I want it to display at bottom of div image
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
      <button type="submit" id="but">
        Information
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need JS for this, just CSS. Set `position: relative` on the parent div, and `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` on the button. Also note that your HTML has at least one syntax error

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I try to position relative in div="row" and absolute ; bottom 0 in my bottom , It wok but the problem is the height of 2 col-md-6 are not the same

Comment: In that case could you edit your question to show a working example of the problem which shows all your HTML and CSS. Right now it's almost impossible to fix an issue we can't see.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38358/ Update this fiddle with your requirement. You want to match the height of both sibling div's ?

Comment: @Krishna9960 thanks

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i updated sir

Comment: where's the updated fiddle Link ??

Comment: check this example - you could do something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38359/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38358

Comment: that is just for the equal height though - has nothing to do with the button :-D

Comment: Ok from the solution you accepted as what you wanted to accomplish you probably have to change dramatically your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 50px">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
      <div style="background-color:red;height:456px;"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6" style="text-align: right;">
      <h1 id="head-font" style="font-weight: bolder; margin: 0;">TITLE</h1>
      <label id="p-font" class="text-font">INFO</label>
      <p class="title text-font" id="p-font" >promotion description</p>
      // this buttuon I want it to display at bottom of div image
   </div>
   <button type="submit" id="but">
   Information
   </button>
</div>


//CSS Code


.row{
  position: relative;
}
#but{
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right: 3%;
}
```

Updated Fiddle Link https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38362/
Slightly changed the structure of HTML.

You can swap the red background to right then change the css to the following

```
#but {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 37%;
}
```

Comment: Hope you understood what we did here. We made the row relative and the button absolute. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/hhhy8uhv/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 50px">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">       
      <h1 id="head-font" style="font-weight: bolder; margin: 0;">TITLE</h1> 
      <label id="p-font" class="text-font">INFO</label>
      <p class="title text-font" id="p-font" >promotion description</p>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6"> 
      <div style="background-color:red;height:456px;width:100%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center">
      <button type="submit" id="but">
        Information
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution is without `jQuery`, just by placing the containers.

**One more solution** https://jsfiddle.net/hhhy8uhv/1/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">       
      <h1 id="head-font" style="font-weight: bolder; margin: 0;">TITLE</h1> 
      <label id="p-font" class="text-font">INFO</label>
      <p class="title text-font" id="p-font" >promotion description</p>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6"> 
      <div style="background-color:red;height:456px;width:100%;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center">
      <button type="submit" id="but">
        Information
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Include one more `row` and there you can keep the button.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: How can i put my button in col-md-6  ( left-side )

Comment: @user8663822 You mentioned `bottom of div image` in your code. Please let me know what you are looking for.

Comment: If you want to put it in the left side just set your classes in the wrapping button div like this     <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">. If you want to put your button in the right side put your classes in the wrapping button div like this     <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-6 col-sm-offset-6 col-lg-offset-6">. According to the sulotion @Shiladitya has provided you. You have to change the arrangement of your divs. And you should read more about the bootstrap grid.

Comment: I try to place  Information button  = height of div image @Shiladitya

Comment: @user8663822 Welcome buddy :) Give me some time, will provide you a best solution.